# A simple question about a bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f$ be a function defined on $[0,\infty)$. If $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $ x \in [0, \infty)$, then can I say   $$ \exists C,R >0 : |f(x)| \leq \frac{C}{(1+x)^2}\;\;(x \geq R) $$
is equivalent to $$ \exists C >0 : |f(x)| \leq \frac{C}{(1+x)^2} \;\; (\forall x \in [0,\infty))\;?$$
I think this is true because for $ x \in [0, R)$, $$ |f(x)| \leq M = \frac{M(1+x)^2}{(1+x)^2} \le \frac{M(1+R)^2}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{C'}{(1+x)^2}.$$
I want to know that my statements are true or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  In particular, you have shown that if there exist $R$ and $C$ as specified in the first equation, you can take $C$ in the second equation to be the maximum of $C$ and $C'$.  Thus the first equation implies the second.  And the second equation also implies the first (pick $R$ to be anything at all).  Thus, the two equations are equivalent.

Comment: thanks for pointing my error out. I didn't read the last row carefully , sorry.